# How to fix bcrypt Type Error - "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, hash, bcrypt

when I run my code which is provided below I get a type error that says "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing". At first I thought it may be something to do with the input statement but after trying it with the password set as a normal string it still did not work. I'm sorry in advance if this is a really easy solve but I'm new to python and couldn't find any other answers on here or any other websites. I'm using python 3 if that info helps you.

My code:

```
import bcrypt 

password = input("Input your desired password: ")
hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, an instance of the `bytes` type instead of the `str` type is required. This should probably solve your problem

```
import bcrypt 

password = input("Input your desired password: ")
b = password.encode('utf-8') # I just added this line
hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashpw(b, bcrypt.gensalt()) # dont forget to change "password" -> "b"
```

Good Luck!